# How to pass json data to html form?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I am trying to pass json data after successfully received the array, but what i am trying to pass to modal window to edit the values. data is array actually have the values but not passing to the html form.

```
   function passvalue(val,start,end)
   {
       var id=val;
       var start=start;
       var end =end;
        //var dataString = "id=" + id;
       $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get-results.php",
        data: {id:id},
       // dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) 
           {
                 //console.log(data);
                $('#ctemail').val(data.cemail);

           }
});

   }
```

And my html is:
 
                            **Enter Customer Email**

Comment: my html  <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleCustEmail"><strong>Enter Customer Email</strong></label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Customer Email" name="ctemail" id="ctemail">
                        </div>

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the body of your question (**not** in a comment) for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected some shortcomings.

```
function passvalue(val,start,end)
{
    var id=val;
    var start=start;
    var end =end;
        //var dataString = "id=" + id;
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get-results.php",
        data: 'id='+id, // multiple: data: 'id='+id+'&id2='id2,
        // dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json_data) 
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(json_data); // Json parse
            //console.log(data);
            $('#ctemail').val(data.cemail);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanku for your help

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. Mark my comment verified, please. :)